# How to fix "Unable to copy file...access is denied" when using docker build

Tags: .net, docker, build, dockerfile, containers

I am trying to build my API into a container with docker but it's giving me this really annoying error that I can't seem to get around no matter how much I change the code. I have tried changing the files from read-only but they simply go back afterwards, I have also tried restarting VS and re-building the project.

**Error:**
#15 3.551 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5097,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "/src/obj/Release/net6.0/apphost" to "bin/Release/net6.0/WebAPI". Access to the path '/src/bin/Release/net6.0/WebAPI' is denied. [/src/WebAPI.csproj]

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebAPI.csproj", "WebAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

**.dockerignore:**

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
```

P.S This is the Dockerfile that was automatically created when I added docker support, I also tried coding it completely differently and still had that exact error

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you're copying in your bin and obj folder from your source into the Docker container on this line:

`COPY . .`

That will mess up the build. To prevent that, you want to make use of a `.dockerignore` file. This allows you to specify files and paths to be excluded from the Docker build context and not available to be copied into the container.

Here's an example of a `.dockerignore` file that would help:

```
**/bin/
**/obj/
```

Place that file at the root of the directory you use as your Docker build context. For Visual Studio scenarios, that would typically be the directory that contains your solution file.

Comment: I edited the post and included the .dockerignore file